# Exercise 5.16 from Brezis' Functional Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space with scalar product $(\cdot , \cdot )$ and norm $| \cdot |$. Let $V \subseteq H$ be a dense linear subspace and say it has its *own* norm $\|  \cdot \|$ such that $V$ is again Banach for $\| \cdot \|$.

And suppose the injection $V \rightarrow H$ is continuous, i.e, $|v| \leq C \|v\| \forall v \in V$. Consider the operator $T: H \rightarrow V^*$ such that:

$\langle Tu, v\rangle_{V^*, V} = (u, v)_H$ $\forall u \in H, \forall v \in V$. Now:

1. Prove $\|Tu\|_{V^*} \leq C|u|$ for all $u \in H$
2. T is injective
3. $R(T)$ is dense in $V^*$ if $V$ is reflexive
4. $f \in R(T) \iff \exists a\ge0$ such that $|\langle f, v\rangle_{V^*, V}|\leq a|v|$ for all $v \in V$

I feel stupid but I'm not immediately sure here of the rigor here even though intuitively I sorta see it:

Basically $T$ is $i^*$ where $i : V \rightarrow H$ is the inclusion. At this point I think you'll want to use the density of $V$ in $H$ to show injectivity of $T$ I think. But I'm not sure how to show $1$.

Then I'm not sure how to show 3. either.

For 4., $\implies$ is clear enough but not $\impliedby$. I think the idea is to define a new functional $\varphi : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $\varphi(v) = \langle f, v\rangle$ and using the density of $V$ in $H$ to extend to all of $H$.

I would appreciate some help here, for filling in the blanks more formally.

Comment: I don't think $T^*$ is the inclusion in this case...

Comment: $|(u,v)_H|\le |u|\,|v|\le C|u|\,\|v\|.$ This gives 1. If $Tu=0$ then $u $ is orthogonal to $V,$ hence $u=0.$ This gives 2.

Answer (score 1):

1. For any $v \in V$,  $|Tu(v)|= |\langle u,v \rangle| \leq |u||v| \leq C|u|\|v \|$, hence $\|Tu \| \leq C |u|$.
2. Note that T is linear. Then if Tu=0 for some u $\in H$, we have Tu(v)=0 for all $v \in V$, or equivalently, $$\langle u,v \rangle =0 \quad \forall v \in V$$
   Since $V$ is dense, we conclude that $\langle u,v \rangle =0 $ for all $v \in H$, hence $u=0$.
3. Suppose by contradiction that $R(T)$ is not dense in $V^{\star}$ and pick $f \in V^{\star} \setminus \overline{R(T)}$. Since $\overline{R(T)}$ is a closed linear subspace, by Hanh-Banach there exists some $\eta \in V^{\star \star}$ such that $\eta|_{\overline{R(T)}}=0$ and $\eta (f)=1$.  Since V is reflexive, there is some $v \in V$ such that $Jv = \eta$, where $J: V \to V^{\star \star}$ is the canonical map. Therefore, we have $0= \eta(Tu)=Jv(Tu)=Tu(v)=\langle u,v \rangle$ for all $u \in H$, thus $v=0$. This implies that $$1 =\eta(f)= Jv(f)=f(v)=f(0)=0$$
   which is a contradiction.

4. For the reverse implication,the assumption states that $f: V \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded linear functional on $V$ under the norm induced by the inner product. By continuity,we obtain $l \in H^{\star}$ such that $l$ extends $f$. By the Riesz representation theorem, there exists $u \in H$ such that $$l(y)= \langle y,u \rangle \quad \text{ for }y \in H$$
   In particular, for any $v \in V$, $f(v)=l(v)=\langle v,u \rangle = \langle u,v \rangle = Tu(v)$, thus $f=Tu$.